# VS2013 TFS check-in failure: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sql, tfs, visual-studio-2013, database-project, checkin

I am working on converting our SQL Server database into a SQL database project using Visual Studio 2013. There are a couple files that are not checking in because they are getting the error, "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

I am running VS as admin, and I have tried closing and reopening the project, but the error continues.
I do not have this file opened anywhere else... What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Which files won't check in?

Comment: I've used [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) before to resolve the problem. You should try to track down what process is causing this, it might be indicative of something unexpected occurring.